# Interpolate src attribute from file system not as a get request

Tags: html, angular, spring-boot

I have a classic app with spring boot as backend and Angular as Frontend. In the app there is a button to upload an image, this image is saved somewhere in the backend, and the relative path to that image is saved in the db as e.g. "uploads/image.jpeg".

I want to interpolate the src attribute of the `<img>` tag to access those specific files on my server file system. whenever I do that, that path gets converted into **"localhost/4200/uploads/image.jpg"** and issued as a **get** request.

However, if the src attribute is not interpolated it access the normal file without any problems. Only when interpolated does it issue a get request

Angular part:

```
<img class="img-responsive custom-img" src={{article.imageUrl}} referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
```

basically `article.imageUrl = "uploads/image.jpeg"`, why does it get `http://localhost/4200` appended to it ?

Error:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/uploads/image.jpeg 404 (Not Found)
```

I want to disable this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the image dynamically on the client side, there must be a get request for that image.
To load the image without a get request, reload the whole page after a user uploads an image, thus sending a get request for the whole page and not just the image. Now on the server side add the image to the DOM using the local path, and send back the whole hardcoded page to the client.

Comment: why it must issue a get request? it does not make sense. It does not issue one when it is hardcoded why is it different when interpolated?

Comment: yes. this is the angular(client) code. have a look  at the repo https://github.com/elmodeer/simple-blog-project